How can I correctly import an MDX file in React using @mdx-js/react?
I'm trying to import an MDX file in my React project using the @mdx-js/react library, but I'm encountering issues with incorrect import paths.
When trying to import Content.mdx, the resulting path is incorrect and looks like this: /static/media/Content.14f9161674a8b1fcf168.mdx.
Here’s what I have:
DocsLayout.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { MDXProvider } from '@mdx-js/react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import TopBar from './TopBar';
import components from './mdx';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  wrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: '64px 0px 64px 256px',
  },
});

const DocsLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <TopBar onMobileNavOpen={() => setMobileNavOpen(true)} />
      <NavBar onMobileClose={() => setMobileNavOpen(false)} openMobile={isMobileNavOpen} />
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <MDXProvider components={components}>{children}</MDXProvider>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

DocsLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

export default DocsLayout;

SupportView:
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import Page from 'src/components/Page';

const Content = lazy(() => import('!babel-loader!mdx-loader!./Content.mdx'));

const SupportView = () => {
  return (
    <Page title="Postman">
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Content />
      </Suspense>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default SupportView;

Content.mdx:
# Postman

Postman is a free-to-use visual editing tool for building and testing API requests...

package.json:
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.11.0",
    "@date-io/core": "^2.8.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.11",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdx-js/runtime": "^1.6.22",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@sentry/react": "^5.30.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.30.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.3",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.14",
    "change-case": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.6",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "immer": "^6.0.9",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jss": "^10.3.0",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.6-next.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.20.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.3.7",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.6.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-modal-image": "^2.5.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.13.9",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.18.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scrollbars-custom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.28.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@types/history": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "mdx-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }

How can I properly import Content.mdx so that the file path is resolved correctly?

I don't know either, but why not use something like Astro that has mdx support built-in instead of messing with your own bable config?

I'm updating an old project with maintenance and new features, which involves upgrading the dependencies. The documentation section is written in MDX format, and after the version updates, it's broken. Despite my research, I haven't been able to find a solution yet. @mb21

I see. I'd try to narrow it down to a specific package. When you update exactly which package does it break?

mdx-loader and @mdx-js/runtime are really old and unmaintained. I suggest you start by removing those.
Now replace mdx-loader with @mdx-js/loader in the source code:
const Content = lazy(() => import('!babel-loader!@mdx-js/loader!./Content.mdx'));

Also you won’t need babel-loader for MDX, but you can keep it if you want.
const Content = lazy(() => import('@mdx-js/loader!./Content.mdx'));

If you want to use @mdx-js/react, you need to configure providerImportSource
const Content = lazy(() => import('@mdx-js/loader?{"providerImportSource":"@mdx-js/react"}!./Content.mdx'));

I recommend to take it a step further and move the loader into your Webpack configuration instead of using Webpack’s loader import syntax.
